# Python Klein + OAS (Open API) Swagger like integration

Tags: python, openapi

Flask and Django have integrations with swagger allowing API documentation exposure.
Recently I discovered a [Klein](https://github.com/twisted/klein) which is showing good asynchronous performance but I can’t find any existing *bicycle parts* to provide self-documentation exposure to the service some how similar to [flasgger](https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger).

Are there any libraries that I can *knit* into Python Klein app to expose its API in OAS (Open API 3.0) manner or building own bicycle is unavoidable?

Answer (score 0):

Use swagger-ui which is a collection of html, css and js files plus write your own yaml/json specification.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

I didnt find any other way.

Comment: We have already built two bicycles and one heavy cargo ship for this kind of integration. Just do not have enough time to extract the library for the FSF/OSS community. I hope in half year of working on it in my spare time I’ll get it out on GitHub.